# open hidden element on redirect

Tags: jquery, html

I have two .html files (page1.html and page2.html)

Page1.html got links to texts on page2.html

```
<a href="page2.html#text1">page2 - text1</a>
<a href="page2.html#text2">page2 - text2</a>
```

Page2.html has the following code:

```
<a href="#" class="text_link" onClick="$('.desc').slideUp(); $('#text1').slideDown('slow'); return false;">link_to_text1</a>
    <div class="desc" id="text1" style="display:none;">
       <p>text1</p>
    </div>

<a href="#" class="text_link" onClick="$('.desc').slideUp(); $('#text2').slideDown('slow'); return false;">link_to_text2</a>
    <div class="desc" id="text2" style="display:none;">
       <p>text2</p>
    </div>
```

What I want is: link "page2 - text1" should open page2.html and show text1, same for second link. How to make it work? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass params like :

```
<a href="page2.html#text1?show=text1">page2 - text1</a>
<a href="page2.html#text2?show=text2">page2 - text2</a>
```

then use some javascript to get the param on page 2 and then do some hide or show

```
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
if(getUrlVars()["show"]=="text1")
$('#text1').show();
else
$('#text2').show();
```

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html

Answer (score 1):

handle query string "anchors" on `$(document).ready(...` and open block according to anchor

on the second page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var param = window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.indexOf('#')));
   if (param != '' && param != undefined) {
     $(param).slideDown();
   }
});
```

in this case part after '#' should match the elemtn id to be toggled.

Comment: sorry to be picky, they're not 'query string anchors', anchors and query strings are two separate things.